# Android Project Build Fails with Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently installed a fresh copy of Android Studio Version 1.5.1. And i imported a project that was built on a previous version of Android Studio and tried loading into the IDE. But it started giving me this error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\yomal.ds\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
C:\Users\yomal.ds\AndroidStudio_Workspace\ClaimAssistant\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

I checked my gradle.build which was looking fine as far as i could see.
Here's my gradle.build file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.informaticsint.claimassistant"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
}
```

I tried creating a new project and adding previous project sources to the new one. But this error pops up when i set the SDK version to 22.

this is the same thing that happened to me, but the answers didn't work.
[Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name after upgrading to AppCompat v23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

I tried downgrading the support library versions for each of their releases from 22 - 22.2.1

But when i set the project to compile in SDK 23 it works fine but leads to some other problems. This is what happens when i do this.
[resource error in android studio after update: No Resource Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32092511/resource-error-in-android-studio-after-update-no-resource-found)

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project after changing the values.

It seems that you are using: android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse which does not exist. I would recommend searching for that in the project and replace it with something. My guess is that the previous machine had something cached in his m2 folder, which picks up dependecies you don't have

Comment: Also make sure you have the android support library downloaded.

Comment: @JoakimEngstrom Yes i do clean and rebuild the project every-time and i do have the necessary support libraries downloaded. And about the TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button, I don't use it in the project. In fact when i create a new Project it automatically add that values-v23.xml in the following path <Project_path>\<project_name>\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v23\values-v23.xml. Even if i delete this file (Since i do not use it) It is automatically generated again when i sync/clean/rebuild the project.

Comment: I did check on the dependencies for the play services, and they are dependent on a newer version of the support library that you are using.
Maybe you should try bumping the support libraries to the same that the play services are using, which I would think is 23.1.1

Comment: I think this is a dependency issue never the less. If you run gradle dependencies on your APP MODULE, not the root app folder, in the terminal. You will get a nice tree, see that all the support libraries are matching each other. Because every 3:rd party library you are using has dependencies too. If a jar is depending on another version of the support lib, you have to grab a new version of that lib.

Comment: @JoakimEngstrom by Play services you mean the Support Library right (appcompat-v7) ?

Comment: @JoakimEngstrom Assuming that you meant using a higher version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7 library (Sorry if i misunderstood this), there would be a version mismatch right? I want to build this project using API 22 and if i use a 23 Support Library it will give an error. (Please correct me if i misunderstood what you said "Maybe you should try bumping the support libraries to the same that the play services are using, which I would think is 23.1.1")

Comment: But then maybe downgrading the play services in that case. The reason I recommended debugging the dependecies was because of this.

Comment: That said, you could say compileSDK 23 and targetSDK be 22, it's always recommended to use the latest when compiling the app.

Comment: @JoakimEngstrom AFAIK you can't downgrade below the compiling SDK version or use a higher version than the compiling SDK. Yes i always use the same SDK to both compile & target. And also i tried going with the SDK 23 which solves this problem, but leads to other problems. (refer the last link i have posted in the question, that's exactly what happens to me) but i can't resolve that. It rejects apache httpclient dependancies in my project which ultimately leads to compiling errors. Anyway thanks for taking your time to look at this.

Comment: You can have different targetSDK and compileSDK. You can downgrade play services. And with Apache you can add useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' to the gradle file.

Comment: no worries, these kind of things intrest me.

Comment: @JoakimEngstrom i'm trying to build the project with play services 7.5.0. For some reason my project external libraries get updated to version 23 support annotations, appcompat-v7 and  support-v4. Although i have declared my dependencies in the gradle file to use version 22. I noticed that this happens when i add the play services dependency with the + mark. Since it downloads the latest versions of it. So it might be upgrading the rest of the dependencies to its highest levels. I'm trying to build now explicitly setting the version to 7.5.0. Hope this works.

Comment: If it works I can add an answer to this, or you. Whichever you prefer.

Comment: @JoakimEngstrom yes sure you can add it as an answer. For some reason gradle is taking soo much time to run its scripts. It's been 50 mins now still running. Idk wth is wrong with this thing. I had to kill the studio previously since i waited another 50 mins till this thing finish running it's script.

Comment: Gradle :/... I know it sometimes can lock the cache, so to manually remove the gradle cache from both the home folder and project folder. And then do a gradle clean usually fixes these things.

Comment: @JoakimEngstrom it worked :) using play services 7.5.0 did the job.

Comment: Awesome @k9yosh I added an answer to the question. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem, as we figured out in the comments, was a mismatch in dependency.

As the question shows it's compiling against the 22 api version.
The support libraries must correspond to the compile sdk version, which it does in this instance.

But the 8.4.0 Play Services actually depends on the 23+ support libraries, and it's not finding the resources, due to the 22 compileSdk and 22+ version on the support library.

To fix these there are two solutions:

1. Downgrade the Play Services to 7.4.0
2. Upgrade compileSdk and support-library to version 23

The easiest way to debug mismatches in versions are to run

```
 .gradlew dependencies
```

On you app module (no the root of the project), so the terminal command would be something like

```
 cd app-folder/
 ../gradlew dependencies
```

And then check the dependency tree to see if something stands out.

Comment: When i downgrade play services Android studio asks me to install the repository, buy it seem is not available for download anymore. 
I dont want to upgrade compile version because im at the edge of publishing my app, and i don't wanna handle changes in classes error bugs.ç

Comment: @DanielOrdoñez what is the version you want?

Comment: One that works :P, thanks but i finally resolve the issue and downgrade to 7.8, in the next update of my app im going to renew all repositories, put you save my life thanks.

Comment: As I downgrade the Play Services to 7.4.0 it is showing "Error:(95, 0) Version: 7.4.0 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin.
<a href="openFile:/home/sushant/roadcast-locator/RoadCastLocator/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>"