# Android studio : error message

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
```

I literally just downloaded android studio as described by an online course and pressed the build button and got this.I am new to studio,so i have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try figuring out through solutions mentioned in these ?  [Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name after upgrading to AppCompat v23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

[resource error in android studio after update: No Resource Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32092511/resource-error-in-android-studio-after-update-no-resource-found)